# $.getScript() Дописывает параметры в get запросе

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Вызываю`$.getScript("addScript");` запрос летит на сервер вот так `addScript?_=1583674769690`
Откуда образуются этот параметр `?_=1583674769690`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Оказалось что это предотвращение кэширования ответа браузером**

По умолчанию, `$.getScript()` устанавливает настройку cache в значение false. Это добавило метку времени к строке запроса в URL адрес для гарантированного предотвращения кэширования браузером.

Попросил его так не делать:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        cache: true
      });
```